# What do you call the date range slider bar underneath a time series chart?

Tags: controls, charts, sliders

[image]What's the name of a slider bar, underneath a chart, that determines date range, that the chart is showing? The one I circled in pink.

Answer (score 3):

#### If there is a data preview, this is sometimes known as a navigator.

For highcharts, when there is a preview of a larger data set, this is called a **[navigator](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/navigator)**:

> The navigator is a small series below the main series, displaying a view of the entire data set. It provides tools to zoom in and out on parts of the data as well as panning across the dataset.

[image]

Here's **[another example](https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart/examples/functionality/datanavigation/defaultcs.aspx)**:

[image]